# Algorithm for list with Ads

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of `n` items. I want to show an ad after every `y` items, starting after `y` items (not at 0). With this information, how can I determine the total length of the list (original `n` items, plus ads `y`)

Solution must work for all `n`'s and all `y`'s

This is not a homework question or anything like that. I'm building an app and I'm showing a list of items in the sidebar and I want to show an ad after every 5 (variable).

Here's what I've tried:

```
int n = //some integer
int y = //some integer
int counter = n;
int adspacing = y;
if(counter > adspacing-1) {
 for(int i=0;i<n);i++) {
  if(i%adspacing == 0 && i != 0) {
    counter++;
  }
 }
}

return counter;
```

I've spent hours on this and just when I think I got it, I try a certain `n` and certain `y` that causes my app to crash (because `counter` has gotten too large and causes me to reference an array index that is out of bounds).

Comment: Use long variable instead of int;

Comment: "All `n`s and all `y`s"... including `n < 0` or `y == 0`?

Comment: Sorry, all non-negative `n`'s and `y`'s

Answer (score 2):

the number of adds to be shown:

```
n/y
```

The total length of the list is therefore

```
n+n/y
```

Example y= 3 n=3
 xxxA   :   3 + 3/3 = 3 + 1 = 4

Example y= 3 n=5
 xxxAxx :   5 + 5/3 = 5 + 1 = 6

Comment: What if n is 3 and y is 2? n/y = 1.5. I can't render 3+1.5 = 4.5 rows. I need a whole number. How come you are doing +1 in your examples, yet you haven't shown it in (pseudo)code?

Comment: @Adam: No, `n/y` is not 1.5 in any language which uses integral division on integral types, which includes the ones your code looks like.  In other languages, you can just use a `floor` or `trunc` function to throw away the fractional part.

Comment: Think of it as `n+floor(n/y)`. By the way, it's implicit that `y>0`.

Comment: I found it to be close, but incorrect. Does `n+(n/(y-1))` sound correct? It appears to have worked for me for most of my tests. The only reason I ask is because I don't want to not accept your answer based on me not giving enough/the correct information in my question.

Comment: @Adam: please give a concrete counter example.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - This fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/bmyG8/1/ - seems to demonstrate the formula using y-1

Comment: @Adam: Than it should be easy for you to present an example where my calculation returns the wrong value.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - http://jsfiddle.net/ktG23/. Same fiddle, different formula (same as your post). See how it only goes up to 112, despite the fact that there are 116 items in the list.

Comment: @Adam: What `n` what `y`?

Comment: @MrSmith42 - it's in the fiddle, `y = 5` and `n = 117` (`n === list.length`)

Comment: @Adam: `y=5` `n=117` => xxxxxAxxxxxA...xxxxxAxx : length is `6*23 +2 = 140` exactly the result my formula above gives.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - and 140 is the wrong answer - as shown at this fiddle using your formula (http://jsfiddle.net/ktG23/). The correct answer is 146 shown at this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bmyG8/1/)

Comment: xxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxxxxxAxx has 117 `x` and after 5 `x` is always a `A`. That's wrong with this? It has length 140.